# Why is a promise resolved before a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

I have the following set of instructions

```
console.log(1)
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(3)
});
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(4))
console.log(7)
```

The output is:

```
1
7
4
3
```

The order of execution is as follows:

- consoles are executed
- promise resolved
- settimeout executed

Why is the promise resolved before the setTimeout? Both are handled by a callback, right?

Comment: Promises have priority over timers.  So, if both are in the event queue at the same time, then the promise will get serviced first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question. In order to understand the reason, one needs to understand the JavaScript event loop.

`.then()` queues a microtask. Microtasks are executed as soon as the JS call stack empties.

In this case ([but not in all cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/setTimeout#nested_timeouts)), `setTimeout` queues a task in the main task queue. Tasks are queued for external events, timer handlers, rendering (in the browser), etc... If a task calls JS code, the next task will not run until all the microtasks associated with it finish running.

So here's what's happening:

1. Task #1, queued internally by Node.js:

   1. `console.log(1)` logs `1`. **Output is `1`**
   2. `setTimeout(() => { console.log(3) });` queues a *task* to log `3`
   3. `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(4))` queues a *microtask* to log `4`
   4. `console.log(7)` logs `7`. **Output is `1 7`.**
   5. The JS stack empties, because there's no more statements. The microtasks begin to execute.

      1. Microtask #1-1, queued by `.then()`:

         1. Logs `4`. **Output is `1 7 4`.**
2. Task #2, queued by `setTimeout()`:

   1. Logs `3`. **Output is `1 7 4 3`.**
   2. The JS stack empties, because there's no more statements, however there are no microtasks.
      Final output:

```
1
7
4
3
```

Comment: Do all promises go in the microtask queue?

Comment: All `.then()` and `.catch()` callbacks do, as does code after `await` in an async function.

Comment: _".then() queues a microtask"_ - technically, `then` method call queues a job in the micro-task queue to execute the fulfilment handler if the promise is _already resolved_. If the promise is in pending state, `then()` method call appends the fulfilment handler to an internal list containing the fulfilment handlers for a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The Promise `.then()` callback will be invoked immediately after the code block completes. The timer will get a default minimum time of around 15 or 16 milliseconds, so it's definitely going to happen after that.

*edit* — apparently in this crazy modern world the minimum time is around 4ms, not 15 or 16.

Comment: I appreciate this answer and I understand that by the sequence of execution but why it's definitely going to happen after that?

Comment: Not quite... `setTimeout` is instantaneous unless it's called multiple times. In that case, it has a minimum of 4ms. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Timeouts_throttled_to_%E2%89%A5_4ms).

Comment: @D.Pardal uhh no, there's still a few milliseconds of minimum delay. On top of that, there are separate event queues for Promise resolution and things like timers. You misread the very documentation you posted.

Comment: That throttle is only relevant if there are multiple pending timeouts scheduled. There's no throttle for only one timeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: As a reality check, try this: `console.time('timeout');
setTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('timeout'), 0);` For me, it logs ~1.35ms